# Does HTML5 Canvas emit an event when it finishes rendering?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm having a [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27698430/is-canvas-supposed-to-re-render-each-time-the-screen-adjusts-on-iphone-browsers) right now with mobile browsers, trying to use PDF.JS to render PDF files in the browser. It works fine, but I need to render a gradient over the PDF files to hide some of the content, and I don't know how to figure out when the canvas is done rendering the PDF, so I'm setting a 3 second time-out and then running my "callback". It's not pretty, and I think it might be the cause of the problem above, since:

- the issue doesn't happen on desktop browsers at all.
- the issue doesn't happen on mobile if I don't render the gradient.

So my conclusion is that for some weird reason, if the gradient gets rendered before the PDF is finished rendering, the canvas "freaks out".

So, I need to attach a callback to the viewer's rendering operation, really, but I seriously doubt that such a function exists within this poorly documented (but mostly great-working) library.

**Does HTML5 Canvas emit an event when it finishes rendering?** If not, is there any solution that might allow me to ensure that the canvas's rendering is complete?

Comment: There is no something as "finished rendering" available for user code.

Comment: Can you provide an example of your code? Maybe we can help you find a easy way to attach the callback.

Comment: @Cerbrus thank you for offering the help, but the devs of the library beat you to it, impressively, see my self-answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not.
The canvas or it context doesn't have a clue what's actually happening to (/being drawn on) them.

You're going to have to *"attach a callback to the viewer's rendering operation."*

Comment: Just a note about implementing what you suggest. The canvas context (CanvasRenderingContext2D) has relatively few methods that cause the buffered context to be rendered to the display: `stroke, fill, drawImage, strokeText & fillText, strokeRect & fillRect`. You could fairly easily modify `CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype` to wrap these methods and add a callback.

Comment: @markE: Could, sure, but I'd advice against it. Determining what the last call is, so you can execute the callback would be... Messy.

Comment: Agreed, placing a function call in the questioner's code at the appropriate places is cleaner. I just added the note since the OP was asking about using the eventing system. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, it turns out that I was wrong, and (I think this was a recent change?) the PDF JS library is hosted by and integrated natively by Mozilla. So naturally, they are on top of that API with features for just about everything (albeit in a documentation "format" meant more for experienced software engineers, in code form) and the way to attach an event handler for the page's rendering operation completion is implimented here:

https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/web/pdf_viewer.js#L225

and accessed here:

https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/web/viewer.js#L1733

An event, `pagerendered`, is fired.